# Starting a map iterator not at city.begin()

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

In short, when trying to iterate through a map, is it possible to start the iterator at an index/key that isn't *.begin()?

I have a `map` of cities with a class "`City`". (City has coordinates for the city, and in the following code, calc_dist(c1, c2) will calculate the distance between the coordinates).  What I am trying to do is create a "2D Map" (i.e. `map<string, map<string, double>> dist`) that can access the distance between the city by using `dist[city1][city2]`.

to compute the distances I basically create a nested iterator over the cities, and it works, but it's slow when using many cities.  since the distance between cities are symmetric, i can cut the loops in half by storing the distance in the reverse of the map.

what i was hoping to do was start the second iterator at the current city from the first iterator.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ tells me that the order is preserved so I feel like I should be able to do this.

Sample code:

```
// Function create_distance_chart(...)
map<string, map<string, double>> create_distance_chart(map<string, City> c){

    map<string, map<string, double>> dist;

    for (map<string, City>::iterator it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); ++it){

        for (map<string, City>::iterator it2 = c.begin(); it2 != c.end(); ++it2) { // here i can make improvements, i hope

            //calculate distance

            dist[c[it->first]][c[it2->first]] = calc_dist(c[it->first],c[it2->first])// store in map
            dist[c[it2->first]][c[it->first]] = calc_dist(c[it->first],c[it2->first])// store in map in the other direction.  
        }
    }
}
```

in the line

```
for (map<string, City>::iterator it2 = c.begin(); it2 != c.end(); ++it2) {
```

i tried to change `c.begin` to `c[it->first]`, `c.at(it->first)`, just `it->first`, and a dummy variable that pulls the index for `it->first`.

the only other method i'm considering is doing a reverse iterator for the second iterator and having a termination condition that might cause the second loop to end before `it2 != c.end()` (i.e. at the first iterator's city), but i'm not making headway in that domain right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `std::map::find` to find an element and start there.  The `find` method returns an iterator.

Comment: doesn't `it2 = it` work?

Comment: If you are not returning anything, why your function return type is `map<string, map<string, double>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this statment:

```
c[it->first]
```

is a slow and convoluted way to simply say:

```
it->second
```

and as you use that 8 times in your loop there is no surprise it is slow indeed.

And for your loop, looks like you want to change second loop to:

```
for (map<string, City>::iterator it2 = std::next(it); it2 != c.end(); ++it2)
```

Note: if you do not have intention to change values in the map it is cleaner to use `std::map::const_iterator` instead.

Note2: I assumed that calculating distance btw a city and itself is meaningless. If it is not the case in your geometry then remove `std::next()` in above code and just assign `it` to `it2` in the second loop initialization.